# Basic Easy way to login to Facebook using their API

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to know whats the best possible and easiest way to log in to the Facebook through their own API using the Visual Studio C# Win Form Application

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please have a read here. There is a lot of useful information of what you are trying to achieve.

https://developers.facebook.com/